# Postgres date format with Greek day inside

Tags: postgresql, date-format

I am trying to store a date in a Postgres table with the below SQL command

```
update card_order set valid_until = to_date('23/12/17,Σαβ 11:00πμ', 'YYYY-MM-DD,Day HH:MIa');
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid value "Σαβ 11" for "Day"
DETAIL:  The given value did not match any of the allowed values for this field.
```

I have setup my db with

- Encoding UTF8
- Collation Greek_Greece.1253
- Character type Greek_Greece.1253

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to set `lc_time` to a Greek locale and use the `TM` modifier as in `TMDY`.

But that still won't help, because, as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) says:

> `to_timestamp` and `to_date` ignore the `TM` modifier.